# How can I log anything when ZAP receives a communication?

Tags: java, zap

I want to create a ZAP add-on which simply logs something on the console whenever a communication is received. I followed following [tutorial](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/developer/creating-new-addon-in-zap-extensions/) to create a simple add-on, but now I don't know what should I do to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve. Does your plan apply only to Proxied traffic?

Assuming it does:

You'd need to implemented a [ProxyListener](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/3a17da31283ba92c7cd76f2398df590eefbbc592/zap/src/main/java/org/parosproxy/paros/core/proxy/ProxyListener.java) and hook it:

```java
@Override
public void hook(ExtensionHook extensionHook) {
    extensionHook.addProxyListener(getMyProxyListener());
}
```

However, if you aren't set on an add-on, you can simply use a proxy script: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/proxy